# Watermark on animated gif

Tags: php, image-uploading, imagick, animated-gif, watermark

Hi i am having problem with watermarking (*using Imagick*), first i upload my GIF image into `/tmp folder` then i run code from down here

```
$watermark = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/assets/banner.png";
$cmd = " $target_file -coalesce -gravity South ". 
" -geometry +250+0 null: $watermark -layers composite -layers optimize "; 
exec("convert $cmd $watermarked_animation ");
```

Some of them get converted and placed into `/i folder` and they work fine but some of them are just blank (image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo1sf.png)
and listed like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYNPc.png)

Answer (score 0):

can you try to open that file of 10bytes in notepad or similar editor?

What does it say,, sometimes that can help to debug things :)

hth, k

Comment: I opened that file with sublime text editor and it was
     "4749 4638 3961 f401 f600" 
And with notepad http://i.imgur.com/ownGMSF.png
Thanks :)

Comment: hm,, it seams that output is ok,, I was thinking of some good info to find inside.. I think that imagick has some problems with png's alpha or transparent pixels.. does that happen on that kind of images maybe?

Comment: I don't deal with .png images, only .gifs